# Holding two or more variables by one variable

Tags: shell, variable

I know that in various programming languages there is an option to hold two or more variables (or just one variable) by some variable; a typical example in general is to store coordinates.

Is this practice of holding two or more variables by one variable exist in shell (say, Bash) and what would be a typical example?

Comment: Check arrays in bash https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html

Comment: I don't mean to mere arrays holding values (which aren't variables), did you mean to say that arrays in Bash can also include variables inside the array?

Comment: You can use so name associate arrays: https://linuxhint.com/associative_array_bash/

Comment: What do you actually mean by a variable holding another variable? Do you mean like an object having an attribute (in object oriented programming speak)?  Are you specifically interested in the `bash` shell?

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't mean to ask in an OOP specific manner but in a more general manner (a variable has two or more values but these are not mere data-type values such as a string or an array but actually variables with their own values); I would be most glad to get an answer about Bash because that's the only shell I work with, but an example from another shell is fine.

Comment: Keep in mind that in the shell, variables are untyped, i.e. (_apart from arrays_) they are all just strings. Structured types such as a `struct` or `object` in C++ don't exist in the shell, if that is what you are referring to.

Comment: If the number of accesses to the variables is rare, I'm happy to store them as strings like `Position="$x,$y" and split them as `IFS=, read -r x y <<<"${Position}"`. But I would usually take this as a hint that awk or perl might be a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the values out you typically give the values names. For a coordinate example you might use `x` and `y`, and then have some syntax like `point.x` to get to it.

Bash has associative arrays, which are like maps or hash tables in other languages. You can use them as

```
declare -A point
point[x]=3
point[y]=4
echo "${point[x]}"
```

The syntax is ugly, but feature like this need to be added in a (mostly) backward compatible way. The Bourne shell has been around since 1979 (currently 42 years) and it is hard to find new constructs which don't already mean something.

Comment: You can also create (fake) a two-dimensional associative array with "variable" names, by assigning indexes like `D2[hook,x]=45; D2[line,y]=88;`